# Android to .NET image transfer using HTTP Get

Tags: android, emulation

I have successfully send a string from android to .NET using HTTP GET, I am using WCF in the .NET end, my real intention is to send an image from android mobile to .NET server, can I use GET for this, ie, convert the image into base64 string and then send the image to .NET just like I did for the string? If no, why is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

GET would append the Base64 encoded string representation of the image to the URL. URLs have length limitations hence the entire string may not get transferred.
A better approach would be to use POST with JSON data to hold the Base64 encoded image string.

Comment: So there is no way to send data using GET without adding the string to URL?

Comment: Look, the only way to get information across using GET is using parameters. The parameters get appended to the URL in the form _param1=value1&param2=value2...._

Comment: Yes I get that now, GET is not meant for sending information, I think it just meant for GETing the information, to know which information we require, we send a parameter, the primary aim of the GET is to GET information.

Comment: Correct. You GET it now.